# Data capture from flash application

Tags: c#, flash, capture

I'm implementing software to casino auto-play. I'm using .NET technology and C# language.
The main problem is how to capture data from casino game (here is the link to the game  http://www.bet-at-home.com/redirNetentCasino.aspx?game=lrblackjack2-3h&pff=True ). I have never been dealing with Flash so I don't know a lot about this technology.

Well, I know that In the game we have server and client. Server is sending data to client and client is responding. For example server is sending information about dealt cards. My question is it's possible to capture data sent by server to client, I quess it is?? I need to now what kind of card I'm receiving. This data is sent in readable format or is ciphered?? Could you give me some hints?

The second option is to use a screen capture.. but this is very slow method. What are you thinking??

Thank you for help.

Regards,
Pablo

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Dont use the screen capture method - like I did - the site will change over time. I suggest looking at [existing software](http://www.pokerbot-online.com/) before rolling your own.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do to interpret data from the game. First, you can use CheatEngine which is mostly the choice of Flash game hackers. The following links will help you get started:

[How to hack flash games with cheat engine 5.5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ucf-wO7Wqk0)
[How to Cheat and Hack Flash based Games](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-cheat-and-hack-flash-based-games/)

The above method will not work for server based games like the ones hosted on Facebook. So, your second choice is capturing the network traffic and see what you can gather to attain the required information. For capturing the network from C#, you can use [Pcap.NET](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/). But before you try to do it programmatically, you should try it doing using Fiddler, which gathers plethora of information for you whenever you surf a website or when a plugin like Flash makes use of web.
[Get Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) and GL !